# QML Tableview resize column width by dragging the column header border

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I want to resize the column width of a table by dragging the column header border as it can be done in MS Excel. The following code is for my generated table. By default, it is not enabled in TableView (listed here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview-members.html).  What am I missing?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


TableView {
    id: dataPreviewResult

    columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return 100; }
    rowHeightProvider: function (column) { return 30; }
    anchors.fill: parent
    topMargin: columnsHeader1.implicitHeight
    width: parent.width
    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{}
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
    clip: true
    boundsBehavior : Flickable.StopAtBounds


    Connections{
        target: QueryModel

        function onSqlHasData(hasData){
            dataPreviewResult.model = hasData === true? QueryModel: ""
        }

        function onHeaderDataChanged(tableHeaders){
            mainRepeater.model = tableHeaders
        }

    }

    delegate: Rectangle {
        border.color: Constants.darkThemeColor
        border.width: 0.5

        Text {
            text: display
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            elide: Text.ElideRight
            color: Constants.lightGrayTextColor
        }
    }
    Rectangle { // mask the headers
        z: 3
        y: dataPreviewResult.contentY
        x: dataPreviewResult.contentX
        width: dataPreviewResult.leftMargin
        height: dataPreviewResult.topMargin
        border.color: Constants.themeColor
        border.width: 0.2
    }

    // Table Header Starts

    Row {
        id: columnsHeader1
        y: dataPreviewResult.contentY
        z: 2
        width: dataPreviewResult.width

        Repeater {
            id: mainRepeater

            Rectangle{
                width: dataPreviewResult.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                height: 30
                border.color: Constants.darkThemeColor
                color: Constants.lightThemeColor
                border.width: 1

                Text {
                    id: textName
                    text: modelData
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    padding: 10
                    font.bold: false
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue and use `Qt.Quick.Controls 1.2`. Posting the solution for someone if it helps

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle {
    id: win
    width: 860
    height: 560
    visible: true

    property var roleNames:["a", "b", "c"]
    property var newObject: []

    Connections{
        target: QueryModel

        // This one is for table data
        function onSqlHasData(hasData){
            view.model = hasData === true? QueryModel: ""

        }

        // This slot is for updating headers
        // This is also returning an array of strings
        function onHeaderDataChanged(tableHeaders){
            if(tableHeaders.length > 0){
                roleNames = []
                roleNames = tableHeaders

                for(var i=0; i<roleNames.length; i++){
                    var role  = roleNames[i]
                    var columnString = 'import QtQuick 2.3; import QtQuick.Controls 1.2; TableViewColumn {role: "' + role + '"; title: "' + role + '"; }';
                    newObject[i] = Qt.createQmlObject(columnString, view)
                    view.addColumn(newObject[i])
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // This one is to clear the table
    function clearTable(){
        for(var i=0; i<roleNames.length; i++){
            view.removeColumn(newObject[i])
            delete newObject[i]

        }
    }


    Button{
        id: clearBtn
        text: "Clear"
        height: 30
        onClicked: clearTable()
    }

    TableView {
        id:view
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - clearBtn.height
        anchors.top: clearBtn.bottom
        alternatingRowColors: false
        style: TableViewStyle {
            headerDelegate: Rectangle {
                height: textItem.implicitHeight * 1.2
                width: textItem.implicitWidth
                color: "lightgrey"
                Text {
                    id: textItem
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: styleData.textAlignment
                    anchors.leftMargin: 12
                    text: styleData.value
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                    color: textColor
                    renderType: Text.NativeRendering

                }
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 1
                    anchors.topMargin: 1
                    width: 1
                    color: "black"
                    border.color: "black"
                }
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    width: parent.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "black"
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }

            itemDelegate: Rectangle {
                color: "white"
                Text {
                    id: textItem1
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: styleData.textAlignment
                    anchors.leftMargin: 12
                    text: modelData
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                    color: textColor
                    renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                }
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    width: 1
                    color: "black"
                    border.color: "black"
                }
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    width: parent.width
                    height: 1
                    color: "black"
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```